# Phone_Pc connection problems

Tags: windows-7, usb, phone

I have some problems with the USB connection between my phone (Huawei P8) and my PC (Windows 7 - x64).

## The problem

When I connect my phone to the PC with the USB cable to transfer some files it doesn't automatically appear.

Also, under My Computer, it shows as drive "(F:)" , but when I click on it to open the phone's folder, a message appears: "Insert a removable disk"

## What I tried

- I tried to connect another phone to the same USB port with the same cable and everything worked correctly .
- I tried again to connect the phone (Huawei P8) to the port and I noticed that the Windows sound, the one that start when there's an USB connection, started normally.

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Unlock the phone and check for any USB connection-related notifications. It may prevent data transfer by default for security reasons.

Comment: I have posted it as an answer, please accept it. We'll both get some reputation and the question will be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of Android prevent file transfer by default. It's a security measure - you have to explicitly allow file transfers to prevent unauthorized file transfers (eg. when you connect your phone to an untrusted USB host or rogue charger).

Unlock the phone and look for a *USB connection* notification. Tap it and select *File transfer*.